# Switch password by day on Android?

Tags: security, password

I like to put overly complicated passwords on my phone (currently it has 16 numbers). Is there a way to make the password switch by day? Like every Monday it would be "1234" and Tuesday "4321". I have heard of a system like that, but it might not be a real thing, at least not on phone. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy A51.

Comment: This sounds like the antithesis of a good security policy. Make the system ever-changing & so complex & people start writing them down, or the formula by which they are calculated. You could increase your security by several factors by not using all numbers, for starters.

Comment: Is this specifically about the lock screen password, or everything else? Perhaps there are already 3rd-party lock screen apps that have this capability. However, for other things like specific apps, that depends on each app's capability.

Comment: The common way to have a long lock screen password but an easy to use phone is using fingerprint sensor to unlock the phone. So you only have to type the password about 1-2 times a week.

Comment: I'm already using fingerprints and face recognition, and I'm using default Samsung lock screen. I can easily remember whole code with no issue.

Comment: There is no such thing that generates and switches passwords for you - it would lock you out if the password is good, or it would be easily breakable if you could figure it out (computers can break any password generation logic much faster than us). The best thing you could do is to use a password vault app to store passwords safely and use a password generator to generate secure passwords whenever you want.

Comment: I mean like I would set password for each day without app generating it